# How to override/disable Java EE interceptors?

Tags: jakarta-ee, interceptor

We have a couple of interceptors that are good, when needed, but they are a pita when it comes to testing (arquillian), since a lot of testing scenarios simply don't want to test the interceptors, but other code. So I would like to run tests with the interceptors overridden/disabled in order to allow the tests to focus on what is supposed to be tested in the test and not all the fluff around.

I'd prefer not to touch the existing interceptors, but if there are not other way I have the possibility.

Comment: Show your `beans.xml`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin We are using annotated bean-discovery-mode so beans.xml is not in play for this case.

Comment: You could have one `beans.xml` for testing without the `bean-discovery-mode`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, I added one, but I need other stuff too, like TransactionManager and EntityManager to be injected. I tried to add a beans.xml but I simply lost all other dependencies. 

Right now I think I will rewrite the interceptor to check a test-variable in the context and if the test-variable is there the interseptor wont do its work.

Comment: How do you control the injection of `TransactionManager` and `EntityManager`? Have you consider replicating this settings to your test configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it in the past is having separate beans.xml files for testing and for real application. Then, just modify the classpath accordingly.

However, if you are using annotated bean-discovery-mode, and, therefore, not specify interceptors in beans.xml, this solution will not work.

Comment: How to write the beans.xml so it replaces(?) the interceptor? I have tried to put a beans.xml into the arquillian-war but lost TransactionScope and EntityManager injections, so I ended up in a worse place, but I guess I did it wrong...

Comment: That's the problem. If your interceptor is being registered through beans.xml originally, then you could have just switched the bean.xml to disable it. However, as I can understand, your interceptors are registered through either annotations or some bean.xml that you can not access. In this case, I'm not sure how you disable it and if that is at all possible.